# PHP/MySQL monitor tool/dashboard

Tags: php, monitoring, mysql

So I have tried to Google around a lot, but I feel that the are so many tools out there and I don't find anything that is perfect what I'm after. So I'm currently building a system that has a lot of different databases and 1-3 servers that are syncing data to these databases. And every server that is syncing data has its own dashboard where I can check so they are connected to the right databases and so on. What I'm looking for is a monitor tool that I can integrate with the dashboard to see for example the number of requests done to the server, number of SQL queries running and so on. Well, the more information I can get, the better.

And the requirements I have is, either that I can install the monitor tool direct within the dashboard thru composer. Alternative would be a cloud based solution that will collect the data, but I can install the code that will fetch the data thru composer. But it will also need to have an API in this case, so I can display graphs and so on within the dashboard.

The servers are running PHP 8.1 or 8.0 and the databases are MariaDB 10 or MySQL 8.

I'm open to any suggestions, paid, free or freemium. As long as the pricing is not crazy.